# Is there an affordable way to learn the details of IEC 60950?

Tags: standard

I'd love to read the actual spec, but it costs more than $300.

Is there a good summary somewhere on the web, or maybe a good book about it? I will pay $300 if I have to but I can think of many things I'd rather do with that money.

Comment: the equivalent ansi standards are usually cheaper, but to learn all details, what worth is a summary? You definitely want the whole thing then.

Comment: I kind of expect the real answer to this question to be: "no" :-)

Comment: One standard often points to more standards, so it turns into an expensive proposition that you're not aware of on the way in.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected. I actually found one standard document for free (don't remember which one). After 10 pages (literally!), all it said was basically: "this document imposes no further requirements upon standard xyz.". One sentence! After 10 pages of identification, versioning, legal stuff, "how to read this document" etc. So which documents should I buy for a modbus device with a relay output?

Comment: University libraries and other places (CSA library perhaps for myself) would have copies, and in some cases licensing terms may permit alumni etc. to access documents off-site. I'm sure you could also find some kind of illegal copy on the web, but I would not suggest that.

Comment: Place your trust in the Google...

Comment: @SpehroPefhany -- general university libraries, IME, do *not* carry ISO/ANSI/... standards as part of their collections -- this is restricted to dedicated engineering collections, which often aren't tied into WorldCat and other such ILL mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, answering my own question after some more research.

The short and correct answer to the question posed is probably simply "No".

I've obtained the actual standard now. It is very well written, and very informative.

While bits and pieces of it can be found in various recommendations around the net, it is a 300+ page document, and it simply isn't likely that anyone anywhere will have made a useful and reasonably complete summary of it.

The cheapest option to obtain it legally is probably to buy an old used printed copy.

Comment: Actually take a line from your document and you will usually find it on the net.   I did by searching for iec 60950.